# Cocoa Core Data - best practice to check if object with the same property already exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-data, swift

I would like to check with you the best practice to solve the following task in Core Data framework. In my model one of the property for one object type must be unique. Let's say I have object Account - the property name must be unique - it is not allowed to have 2 accounts with same name.

There are 2 possibilities:

- either I execute validation before I call insert into context -> at this point my new object is still not inserted into context, so I can call fetch from context and check if there is already account with particular name
- or I overwrite built in validation methods and put my validation there as mentioned here: 
  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004807-SW1 - all these validation methods are called only after context is saved

I personally like second case, because my validation would be in model. But the problem is that at this point the object is already inserted into context and therefore if I call fetch, the validation always fails, because also the name of new object counts (even if is still not saved permanently). There is a solution for this however. I can check solely the permanent saved objects by creating new temporary managed object context and call fetch

Is this the best practice to execute such a validation. Or am I missing something or there is better way to do it ?

BR
Lubos

Comment: Why is it important to you, that the existing object with the same name has been already saved? You shouldn't care about it and take the behavior as an advantage.

Comment: Because the requirement is that the bank accounts must not have the same names like "my bank account" or "credit account". What do you mean I should take it as advantage ? It is simply functional data model requirement :)

Comment: If two accounts are not allowed to have the same name, they are not allowed to have the same name before they are saved. Hopefully your "functional data model requirement" applies to data in memory, too. Otherwise it would be no requirement, but praying.

Comment: But the user can enter any name in GUI form. It simply needs to be validated by checking in persistence store if the account with this name already exists there. There are 2 stages of saving: 1. insert new object into context, 2. saving the context. The validation methods are triggered only in case 2

Comment: 1. You shouldn't immediately store the form data into an existing MO for many reasons. There are patterns for that. 2. So in you app I can add a new account with the name "A", do not store that and than add a new account with the name "A" again? 3. Core Data is an ORM. There is no difference between "saved objects" and "inserted objects". There are only objects placed in a graph. Your whole approach is anti-conceptual.

Comment: I think you didn't get me. You get new Account object by inserting it into context like "account = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName" At this moment the object is only in memory. Then I fill all fields from GUI. You can fill here anything - no validation. Validation is called by the core data framework only after I call context save ! I mean validation that is called by the framework like validateForInsert(_error: NSErrorPointer) - my validation is there. In this method I am checking it.This method is recommended by Apple to be extended for validation purposes.

Comment: Another approach would be to execute validations before I call insert, but then I couldn't utilize built in validation methods. I simply don't want to put validation into controller, but in the model so the code is reusable for iOS, OS X

Comment: as far as I understand the linked documentation the model based validation only works for one object, but will not tell you if the property is used already. I would simply perform a fetch with the property. if no object is returned: fine, i can create and save the new one.

Comment: Yes, the fetch is needed in any case. But the problem is that if you execute the fetch in that model based validation, its not going to work if you make the fetch within the same managed object context. You have to do it via another context or create empty temporary one, where the new object is not present

Comment: you don't want to make a fetch from within a model — believe me. Just do the fetch as soon as you get the data and do not even create a model object.

Comment: you mean I should follow the first solution I mentioned in the question ? To make the validation by fetch before inserting of new object into context ?

Comment: you should check, if and object needs to be added or an existing one changed. somewhere apple also describe that. the validation is just to make sure that the object in itself is valid— no umlaute in username, age in a certain range, a postal code format that fits to the country,…

Comment: Well, I would need to check where to put the uniqueness validation with the fetch then. The problem is that if I put it into controller before insert, I would have to repeat that validation for OS X again and other such validations .. The approach with putting the fetch into model (in my case extension using swift) is working ! I just have to create new temporary context. I have to find what apple recommends in this cases.

Comment: @lubos Yes, you should do the check immediately. This is, what I wanted to explain the whole time. There is no value in a "in memory conflicts are okay, but not on disk" policy.

Comment: @Amin Negm-Awad - thanks for the input. I think the best approach is the accepted answer. Simply to make fetch using the same context, but excluding SELF - its in the model and it works just perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about it in the following way. In general, it is advisable to avoid the complexities of multiple contexts, although that too is a pattern demoed by Apple.

Create the new managed object, insert it into the context. Check against existing names. If the name is not valid, prompt for a different name. Repeat until the name is valid. If the user breaks off the process or times out, delete the object.

If you can do that before saving, discarding the object could be as simple as calling `[context rollback];`.

If you do this in a separate controller, you could do it in a child context. If the user terminates the process, you just throw away the context altogether without saving.

If you find a name exists but suspect that it is the name being created you can easily check it it is the same object (you already have a reference to it). You could also do a fetch (or, more efficiently, `countForFetchRequest`) with a predicate that excludes this particular object.

```
NSPredicate(format:"name = %@ && (not self = %@)", account.name, account)
```

Comment: I think this is the direction I'd go - simply to call fetch using mentioned predicate and rollback object if the validation was not successful. Looks better than creating new temporary context just for the purpose to check saved account.